# dotCover in Rider eap

Tags: rider, dotcover

I can't find a way to exclude/filter a project/namespace from dotCover in rider.
Can you please provide a navigation, or a shortcut on how to find the filter menu?

I am using Rider 2018.2.3 EAP, I have installed the dotCover. The operating system is windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering feature is not supported in 2018.2 version, but it's planned for 2018.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-17829.